# Woocommerce getting tracking number from note, and updating tracking number in database

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using ShipStation and when I pay for the shipping label, it sends a note like this to the order in Woocommerce:

Example note:

> Hi-Performance Engine Oil Stabilizer Plus – 15oz Bottle (12128-15oz) x 1 shipped via UPS on July 22, 2023 with tracking number 1ZB91D140225863829.

So I wrote this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order_note_data', 'update_order_tracking_number', 10, 2 );

function update_order_tracking_number( $note_id, $order_id ) {
    // Get the note content
    $note = get_comment_text( $note_id );

    // Check if the note contains "shipped via UPS"
    if ( strpos( $note, 'shipped via UPS' ) === false ) {
        return; // Exit out if the note does not contain the required words
    }

    // Extract the tracking number from the note
    $tracking_number = '';
    $start_pos = strpos( $note, 'tracking number ' );
    if ( $start_pos !== false ) {
        $start_pos += strlen( 'tracking number ' );
        $end_pos = strpos( $note, '.', $start_pos );
        if ( $end_pos !== false ) {
            $tracking_number = substr( $note, $start_pos, $end_pos - $start_pos );
        }
    }

    // Update the order with the tracking number
    if ( ! empty( $tracking_number ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'tracking_number', $tracking_number );
    }
}
```

But that did not work.
I put some code after a every few lines to send me a text message when it reached it and it never fired. So I never got a text message.

I did find an order that was updated with a real tracking number, so I went to phpMyAdmin and searched for it and I found this:

```
/*
        [{"tracking_number":"1ZB91D140225863829","carrier_slug":"ups","carrier_url":"https:\/\/wwwapps.ups.com\/WebTracking\/track?track=yes&trackNums={tracking_number}","carrier_name":"UPS","carrier_type":"define-carrier","time":1689125219,"status":"","last_update":1689135219}]
that data was the value to this key: "_vi_wot_order_item_tracking_data" in this table: "woocommerce_order_itemmeta"

but for some reason it was in there 3 times.
No idea why.
    */
```

I am using a plugin called: "Orders Tracking for WooCommerce" by https://villatheme.com/.

How can I have it update the tracking number that plugin is looking for?
Shipstation only sends it to the note.

So I have it look in that note for what is always there, and the tracking number is always after:
"with tracking number " and before the closing period (.). So I have PHP go get that.

That should leave the tracking number alone. I had it text me that too, so I know if it worked, but the function is never ran. I went into a test order and updated the note to the message above, which is a sample tracking number. It never worked. so I did it again as a "Private Note" and still it did not work.

What can I do?

---

updated:

I changed the add_action to this: "woocommerce_new_order_note_data" and it fired, so I got the first text message where I sent the note, and the note was empty. So how do I first get the note that was just added for whatever order it was added to?

I had it text message me the note_id and it was an Array. so I did another note, and had it text me the print_r of it... and it texted me the number 1. But I know this was not the number 1 note. Not the first order either. So how do I get the note_id of the note just posted for an order?

Comment: [edit] your question and add those clarifications. Comments are not that visible and may get deleted in the future. And for the problem, consider to check with that plugin/theme (and also their support if it helps), if you can't get the data already structured so that you don't need to parse a text message. Parsing requires intensive testing and safeguards because it is easy to make mistakes with unstructured stuff and also the text message may change in the future and then you don't have a fall back and need to intervene for operating the production system.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I did that now. I'll delete my comments now that in the main message. thanks again.